# Django model form: reverse side of m2m not saving

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

After upgrading from Django 1.8 (python 2.7) to Django 2.0 (python 3.6) I have an error with this form and reverse m2m widget:

```
models.py
class Treatment(Model):
  ...

class Specialty(Model):
  treatment = models.ManyToManyField(Treatment, related_name='specialties', blank=True)
  ...
```

.
This is the Form for the treatment model. It allows to also edit the specialties (reverse m2m). It worked fine before the upgrade.

```
forms.py
class TreatDetail(forms.ModelForm):
    specialties = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Specialty.objects.all().order_by('specialty_de'),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('Specialties', False),

    )


    def save(self, commit=True):
        treatment = super(TreatDetail, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            treatment.save()

        if treatment.pk:
            treatment.specialties = self.cleaned_data['specialties']
            self.save_m2m()

        return treatment

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreatDetail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['specialties'].initial = self.instance.specialties.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
        fields = (
            'top_treatment',
            'treatment_de',
            ....)
```

I get this Error:

> TypeError at /customadmin/treatdetail/2/de/ Direct assignment to the
>   reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use
>   specialties.set() instead.
>
> treatment.specialties = self.cleaned_data['specialties']

Of course I tried:

`treatment.specialties.set = self.cleaned_data['specialties']`

The error disappears, but the reverse m2m relation is not saved.

Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing that wrong. You have to add item to `M2M` relation in Django 2.0 like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):
`treatment.specialties.add(self.cleaned_data['specialties'])`  
If `self.cleaned_data['specialties']` is a list of *specialties* - you have to iterate over them and add one by one in the same way to your `treatment.specialties`.

Comment: ah, I see. thanks. I solved with `treatment.specialties.clear()` and `treatment.specialties.add(*self.cleaned_data['specialties'])`

Comment: If you use `set()` instead of `add()` then you don't have to call `clear()` first.

Comment: @Alasdair can you please explain what do u mean or provide a link to the explanation? After your words I really find a `.set()` method in `m2m` docs, but there is only 1 row with its description and it is unclear. (As I understand you can actually add a lists instead of single items with that? did you mean something different?)

Comment: The answer above says to use `treatment.specialties.add(self.cleaned_data['specialties'])`. Since `self.cleaned_data['specialties']` is a list, you would need to change that to `treatment.specialties.add(*self.cleaned_data['specialties']) 
`. I am suggesting that you use `treatment.specialties.set(self.cleaned_data['specialties'])` instead, so that you don't have to call `clear()` first. There's an example of using `set()` in the [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) docs.